# MacVim NERDCommenter, how to specify alternative delimiters

Tags: vim, nerdcommenter

When I'm editing **html** and **xhtml** files in **MacVim**, sometimes I need to comment **embedded css styles**, so when I try to switch to the alternative set of delimiters ( ca ), the plugin warns me with:

NERDCommenter:cannot use alternative delimiters, none are specified

My question is:

how can I specify these alternative delimiters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added these lines to my **.vimrc** :

```
let g:NERDCustomDelimiters = {
    \ 'html': {  'left': '<!-- ', 'right': '-->', 'leftAlt': '/*','rightAlt': '*/' },
    \ 'xhtml': {  'left': '<!-- ', 'right': '-->', 'leftAlt': '/*','rightAlt': '*/'}, 
\}
let NERD_html_alt_style=1
```

NOTE: Don't forget about the commas after the curly braces!! :)

Answer (score 3):

These can be specified in the config variable `g:NERDCustomDelimiters` (before the plugin is sourced, e.g. in your `~/.vimrc`):

```
:let g:NERDCustomDelimiters = {
\ 'html': { 'left': '<!-- ', 'right': '-->', 'leftAlt': '/*', 'rightAlt': '*/' }
\ }
```

Comment: I did that, and I also put this line after:
    let NERD_html_alt_style=1
And it worked, but strangely this morning it doesn't. I didn't install any other plugin or did any change to .vimrc
I'm using MacVim by the way.

Comment: Well, after reading my last comment it occurred to me, hey, put those lines in **.gvimrc** , I did it and it seems it's working.

Comment: It stopped working on **MacVim**, it only works in **vim**. 
I don't know how is that possible, I have that lines in both **.vimrc** and **.gvimrc**.
Any ideas?

Comment: .gvimrc shouldn't work, it is sourced _last_, after the plugin. Check with `:scriptnames`; it must come _before_ the NERDCommenter plugin!

Comment: I have those lines you gave me in my **.vimrc** before the NerdCommenter itself is sourced, and since I'm using pathogen to source all my plugins, that means that the lines go before pathogen lines, am I right?
I guess I am, because the plugin works **perfectly** when I'm running vim inside the terminal.(I can switch between alt comments without any problem)
The problem comes when I'm using **MacVim**, I type <leader>ca and:
**NERDCommenter:cannot use alternative delimiters, none are specified**

Comment: I don't know MacVim, but as I said, `:scriptnames` should tell you the order in which things have been sourced.

Comment: Oh my gosh! It has worked all the time, thing is I think it didn't because sometimes I was trying it with **xhtml files** I didn't realize it until I typed **:set filetype?** and vim answered **filetype=xhtml** so it works for html, my question is now, how do I set it up to xhtml as well?